# wxPython, trying to removing all buttons from a sizer, always leaves one remaining

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code to add 6 buttons to a BoxSizer

```
for word in words:
    btn = wx.Button(self, label=word)
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onWordSelect)
```

In my `onWordSelect` method I'm trying to remove all the buttons I've created on the Sizer, so that I can recreate new buttons. My problem is that all the buttons gets removed except for the last one.

Here is my code for removing the buttons:

```
for child in self.sizer.GetChildren():
    self.sizer.Remove(child.Window)
    self.sizer.Layout()
```

When checking `len(self.sizer.GetChildren())` it returns `0`, but the last button is still visible on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

From http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Remove :

> For historical reasons calling this method with a wx.Window parameter is depreacted, as it will not be able to destroy the window since it is owned by its parent. You should use Detach instead.

You removed elements from the sizer but they still exist, being printed one over the other: add one line in your loop to `destroy` or `hide` them and it should be good.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a bit of delving through the documentation I've found that the easiest way of removing all the controls is to use `self.sizer.DeleteWindows()` instead of removing each Button individually in a loop.

Comment: It appears that the api has changed as of wxpython 4.10  and calling DeleteWindows() now raises an exception. It seems that one should now call the Clear( True) on the sizer.

Answer (score 0):

Further to kraymer's answer, an example of toggling the log. Thanks, kraymer!

```
def onToggleLog(self, e):

    self.showlog = not self.showlog

    if self.showlog:
        self.sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.log.Show()

    else:
        self.sizer.Detach(self.log)
        self.log.Hide()

    self.sizer.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarity of kraymer's destroy comment, here's how I solved an issue I was having:

```
class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def__init__(self, title):
        #make the FlexGridSizer specifying only the columns, not the rows
        #make a panel
        #create widgets with the panel as the parent
        #add widgets to the sizer
        self.addLastRow()
        #set the sizer, call layout, etc...

    def addLastRow(self):
        lastBtn = wx.Button(self.myScrolledPanel, -1,"Add New Row", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        numBlanks = self.numTotalColumns-1
        for i in range(numBlanks):
            self.myFlexGridSizer.AddF(wx.StaticText(self.myScrolledPanel, -1, ''), wx.SizerFlags(0))
        self.myFlexGridSizer.AddF(lastBtn, wx.SizerFlags(0))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddNewRowElements, addButton)

    def removeLastRow(self):
        myFlexGridItems = self.myFlexGridSizer.GetChildren()
        for i in range(self.numTotalColumns):
            myFlexGridItems[len(myFlexGridItems)-1].GetWindow().Destroy()

    def AddNewRowElements(self, event):
        self.removeLastRow()
        #add elements
        self.addLastRow()
        self.myFlexGridSizer.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this :

```
buf = []
for word in words:
    btn = wx.Button(self, label=word)
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onWordSelect)
    buf.append(btn)
......
for n,i in enumerate(buf):
    self.sizer.Hide(buf[n])
    self.sizer.Remove(buf[n])
    self.sizer.Layout()
```